# CircleCI config error - Job may be a string reference to another job

Tags: circleci

I don't know how to solve an error in my CircleCI config file.

**config.yml**

```
version: 2.1
executors:
  node-executor:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:14.9.0
commands:
  gatsby-build:
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - yarn-cache-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: yarn install
      - save_cache:
          key: yarn-cache-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
          paths:
            - ./node_modules
      - run:
          name: Gatsby Build
          command: yarn build
workflows:
  version: 2
  build-deploy:
    jobs:
      - release:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - master
jobs:
  release:
    executor: node-executor
    working_directory: ~/tau-guide-website
    steps:
      - gatsby-build
      - run:
        name: Deploy
        command: |
          #upload all the code to machine
          scp -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ./ bitnami@1.1.6.5:~/stack/apps/test
```

When I try to run `circleci config validate`, I get:

```
Error: ERROR IN CONFIG FILE:
[#/jobs/release] 0 subschemas matched instead of one
1. [#/jobs/release] only 1 subschema matches out of 2
|   1. [#/jobs/release/steps/1] 0 subschemas matched instead of one
|   |   1. [#/jobs/release/steps/1] 3 schema violations found
|   |   |   `when`/`unless` step
|   |   |   1. [#/jobs/release/steps/1] extraneous key [command] is not permitted
|   |   |   |   `when`/`unless` step
|   |   |   |   Permitted keys:
|   |   |   |     - when
|   |   |   |     - unless
|   |   |   |   Passed keys:
|   |   |   |     - run
|   |   |   |     - name
|   |   |   |     - command
|   |   |   2. [#/jobs/release/steps/1] extraneous key [name] is not permitted
|   |   |   |   `when`/`unless` step
|   |   |   |   Permitted keys:
|   |   |   |     - when
|   |   |   |     - unless
|   |   |   |   Passed keys:
|   |   |   |     - run
|   |   |   |     - name
|   |   |   |     - command
|   |   |   3. [#/jobs/release/steps/1] maximum size: [1], found: [2]
|   |   |   |   `when`/`unless` step
|   |   |   |   SCHEMA:
|   |   |   |     maxProperties: 1
|   |   |   |   INPUT:
|   |   |   |     run: null
|   |   |   |     name: Deploy
|   |   |   |     command: |
|   |   |   |       #upload all the code to machine
|   |   |   |       scp -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ./ bitnami@1.1.6.5:~/stack/apps/test
|   |   2. [#/jobs/release/steps/1] expected type: String, found: Mapping
|   |   |   Shorthand commands, like `checkout`
|   |   |   SCHEMA:
|   |   |     type: string
|   |   |   INPUT:
|   |   |     run: null
|   |   |     name: Deploy
|   |   |     command: |
|   |   |       #upload all the code to machine
|   |   |       scp -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ./ bitnami@1.1.6.5:~/stack/apps/test
|   |   3. [#/jobs/release/steps/1] maximum size: [1], found: [2]
|   |   |   long form commands like `run:`
|   |   |   SCHEMA:
|   |   |     maxProperties: 1
|   |   |   INPUT:
|   |   |     run: null
|   |   |     name: Deploy
|   |   |     command: |
|   |   |       #upload all the code to machine
|   |   |       scp -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ./ bitnami@1.1.6.5:~/stack/apps/test
2. [#/jobs/release] expected type: String, found: Mapping
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
name: Deploy

command: |
```

I think these need to be indented 1 more level. Does that lessen/resolve the error?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that was the issue.